# Proof: identitiy of $f_1(t)$, $f_2(t)$ for $t\in(0,1)$

Tags: proof-explanation

During solving some spherical problem by 2 independent ways I found "two" solutions represented by $f(t)$

$$f_1(t)=\frac{\sqrt{1+t}(2-t)}{t(\sqrt{1+t}-\sqrt{1-t)}},$$

and

$$f_2(t) =\frac{(t-2)(1-t^{2}+\sqrt{1-t^{2}})}{t^{2}(t-1-\sqrt{1-t^{2}})},$$

where $t\in(0,1)$. Suprisingly, both formulas seem to be identical for any $t\in(0,1)$, which I found challenging. For example, $f_1(0.5)=f_2(0.5)=7.0981$. Hence, I tried to verify their identity

$$
\begin{align*}
f_{2}(t) & =\frac{(2-t)\left[(1-t)(1+t)+\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1+t}\right]}{t^{2}(\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1-t}+\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1+t})},\\
 & =\frac{(2-t)\left[\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1-t}(1+t)+\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1+t}\right]}{t^{2}(\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1-t}+\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1+t})},\\
 & =\frac{(2-t)\left[\sqrt{1-t}(1+t)+\sqrt{1+t}\right]}{t^{2}(\sqrt{1-t}+\sqrt{1+t})},
\end{align*}
$$

but my attempts after few steps finished :-).

Could I kindly ask for your help? Thank you very much...

**Updated proof:**

Multiplying $f_{1}(t)$ by $\sqrt{1+t}+\sqrt{1-t}$  leads to:
$$
\begin{align*}
f_{1}(t) & =\frac{(2-t)\left[1+t+\sqrt{1+t}\sqrt{1-t}\right]}{2t^{2}},\\
 & =\frac{(2-t)(1+t+\sqrt{1-t^{2}})}{2t^{2}}.
\end{align*}$$

Multiplying $f_{2}(t)$ by $t-1+\sqrt{1-t^{2}}$ leads to:

$$
\begin{align*}
f_{2}(t) & =\frac{(t-2)\left[t-t^{3}+t\sqrt{1-t^{2}}-t^{2}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\right],}{2t^{3}(t-1)}\\
 & =\frac{(2-t)\left[t^{2}-1+\sqrt{1-t^{2}}(t-1)\right]}{2t^{2}(t-1)},\\
 & =\frac{(2-t)\left[(t-1)(t+1)+\sqrt{1-t^{2}}(t-1)\right]}{2t^{2}(t-1)},\\
 & =\frac{(2-t)(1+t+\sqrt{1-t^{2}})}{2t^{2}}.
\end{align*}
$$

Hence, $f_1(t)=f_2(t).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator of $$f_1(t)=\frac{\sqrt{1+t}(2-t)}{t(\sqrt{1+t}-\sqrt{1-t})}$$ by $$\sqrt{1+t}+\sqrt{1-t}$$
and multiply numerator and denominator of $$f_2(t)=\frac{(t-2)(1-t^2+\sqrt{1-t^2})}{t^2(t-1-\sqrt{1-t^2})}$$ by $$1-t+\sqrt{1-t^2}$$

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: Thanks, the proof has been updated.